# I am stuck with an example of direct limits and need help to prove $\mathbb{Q/Z} = \varinjlim \mathbb{Z}/(i)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $N$ denote the set of positive integers that are ordered as $m \le n \iff m | n$.

Let $X_m = \mathbb{Z}/(m)$ denote the set of integers $x \mod m$.

I want to show that the direct limit of $X_i$, over $i \in N$, is $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ (using the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit#Direct_limits_in_an_arbitrary_category)).

---

I have defined maps $f_{mn} : X_m \to X_n$ given by: $x \mod m \mapsto xd \mod n$, where $d$ comes from $n=md$.

I also have maps $\phi_m : X_m \to \mathbb{Q/Z}$ given by: $x \mod m \mapsto x/m$.

Then it was easy to check that $\phi_n \circ f_{mn}=\phi_m$.

Now it gets confusing for me. We have to show that if we pick another object $Y$ together with morphisms $\psi_m : X_m \to Y$ such that we have $\psi_n \circ f_{mn}=\psi_m$ then there exists a unique morphism $u \colon \mathbb{Q/Z} \to Y$ such that $u \circ \phi_m=\psi_m$ and $u \circ \phi_n=\psi_n$. I want to know how to do that?

Comment: $\Bbb{Q/Z} = \bigcup_n (n^{-1}\Bbb{Z)/Z} \cong \varinjlim \Bbb{Z/nZ}$. For $Y = \Bbb{Q/Z}$ then $u$ will be in the endomorphism ring of $\Bbb{Q/Z}$ wihich is $\hat{\Bbb{Z}}=\varprojlim  \Bbb{Z/nZ} $ the profinite integers

Comment: @reuns: Thank you for commenting. So I thought $Y$ has to be arbitrary... but then even if we take $Y=\mathbb{Q/Z}$ things seem to get complicated as you indicate. I'm somewhat out to shape and have forgotten quite a lot but would like to know more about the endo ring of $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ and the profinite integers if you can provide more details, or point to where I should look.

Comment: Hint: the unique morphism $u$ should satisfy $u(a/m) = \psi_m(a)$; so make that definition and check the several required properties.

Comment: @GregMartin: Thanks. I want to comment, however, what happens if $a = s/t$ with $\gcd(s, t)=1$? Taking the definition you're suggesting doesn't make sense to me in this case. Would we define $u(a/m)=\psi_{tm}(s)$?

Comment: @GregMartin: Working with the definition you suggested, I can show that $u$ satisfies the commutativity conditions (this is built into the definition) and also show that $u$ is a unique group homomorphism (it isn't required that $u$ be an isomorphism, right?). Also, this feels a bit like an unsatisfying end to the question... what would go wrong if I just tried to show the limit was only $\mathbb{Q}$? Using the definition of you gave, what would go wrong in this case?

Comment: No, $u$ doesn't have to be an isomorphism ($Y$ can be the zero object for example). If you replaced $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ by $\Bbb Q$, what would replace the maps $\phi_m$? This is a good question to ask, because it helps really indicate why the universal property really does pin down the direct limit.

Comment: @GregMartin: I see that defining it simply as $\phi_m(x \mod m)=x/m \in \mathbb{Q}$ doesn't work because it isn't well-defined. I just realized that $Hom(\mathbb{Z}/(m), \mathbb{Q})=0$. So I guess this is where things break down if I try to replace replace $\mathbb{Q/Z}$ with $\mathbb{Q}$. I don't have anything else to ask right now but if there is something that I should know, please tell. And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The direct limit of the directed system  $<X_m,f_{mn}>$ in the category of sets is $\sqcup X_i /\text{equivalence relation}$.

Then we define a bijection as follows
\begin{align} 
\sqcup X_i /\text{equivalence relation} &\rightarrow \mathbb{Q/Z}\\
x_i&\rightarrow \frac{x}{i}\\
m_n&\leftarrow \frac{m}{n}
\end{align}
where $x_i$ is an integer in set $X_i$, $\frac{m}{n}$ are chosen such that $m<n$.